# Which pressure mode of operation has the most stress on aircraft frame

Tags: aircraft-design, airframe, acs-pressurization

So I am want to know which mode of pressurization has the most demand on the airframe

## Isobaric mode

## constant - differential mode

## unpressurized

I hope to get an answer because I have an exam and need to know
Thank you very much

Comment: So what is your understanding on each mode? What is your answer? We can help you but we cannot study for your exam.

Answer (score 1):

Isobaric mode causes the most stress if you keep the cabin pressure and climb higher and higher. (Because the delta pressure and thus the forces become higher and higher)
That's why at high altitudes the isobaric mode is no longer used and the cabin pressurization switches to constant differential pressure instead, which limits the maximum stress.
And unpressurized, well that is not really stressing the hull at all